# Who is depicted on this image showing major Discworld characters?

Tags: character-identification, discworld

[image]

Source: https://twitter.com/PaulKidby/status/857882705165524992.

I only recognize Twoflower the Tourist, Death, the Luggage and the Librarian. However, I'm only a couple of books in the series, so I'm not yet familiar with everyone.

Who is depicted on this image?

Comment: What about Death of Rats?

Comment: I see Evil Harry Dread and some of his goons, and what looks like Cohen out on the far left.

Comment: As I said, I've only just started on Sourcery (book 4?) so I'm not yet familiar with everyone. That's why I created this question, so we as a community can create a legend for this picture.

Comment: Death, Mort, Oto Chriek, Juliet Stollop, Rincewind, Lord Vetinari, Mustrum Ridcully, Ponder, Nanny Ogg, Twoflower, Gladys, Lobsang Ludd, Slant, Fred Colon, Nobby Nobbs, Cherry, Littlebottom, Adora Dierhart, Betty, Ill try to recognize more :D

Comment: Where's Hogfather or Mr. Teatime? Definitely not ALL major characters.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Big guys at the back:

[image: Trolls]

- Diamond, King of Trolls
- Chrysoprase, gangster, with his muscle behind him
- A golem, most likely Dorfl
- Sergeant Detritus

Humanoids, back/main row, left to right:
[image: Humanoids]

- Nijel the Destroyer (red hair)
- Moist von Lipwig (golden hat)
- Adora Belle Dearheart (severe hair and cigarette holder)
- Future denizen of the scorpion pits (the mime)
- Sergeant Fred Colon (short, armoured)
- Commander Sam Vimes (cigar and dragon)
- Queen Magrat
- Probably Foul Ole Ron (top hat)
- King Verence II (the jester)
- Otto Chriek, the vampire photographer (vampire hair and dark glasses)
- "Granny" Esme Weatherwax (witch)
- Casanunda the Dwarf (he tries harder, and has a stepladder)
- Ponder Stibbons (wizard hat, glasses)
- The Dean (Back, red hat)
- Archchancellor Mustrum Ridcully (brown hat)
- Lord Havelock Vetinari (black hair, better not see the mime...)
- Rincewind (red hat, wet)
- Leonard of Quirm (bald)
- Mort, Duke of Sto-Helit (redhead)
- Death
- Ysabel, Duchess of Sto-Helit (blonde hair, rear)
- Susan Sto-Helit (white hair with black streak)
- Alberto Malich (grumpy old geezer)
- Lord Downey (back, top hat)
- Captain Carrot (armour)
- Captain Angua (blonde)
- ??? (bat...werewolf...thing?)
- Doctor Whiteface (clown, back)
- Lu-Tze (monk)
- Reg Shoe (zombie)

Humanoids, front row:

[image: Front row]

- Gimlet the dwarf (holding rat-on-a-stick)
- Cohen the Barbarian (eyepatch)
- Nobby Nobbs (species uncertain)
- ??? (Dwarf)
- Tiffany Aching (frying pan)
- "Nanny" Gytha Ogg with Greebo (witch with a cat)
- The Luggage (travelling trunk)
- Twoflower (glasses and iconograph)
- A.E. Pessimal? (Red hood and glasses) (Possible, given the association with watchmen nearby)
- Cheery Littlebottom (female dwarf)
- Igor (one of them)
- ??? (Dwarf)

Animals and smalls (Bottom row):

[image]

- Wee Mad Arthur (riding the pigeon)
- Mr. Fusspot? (dog)
- Errol (dragon)
- ??? (a goblin)
- The Nac Mac Feegle (gnomes, front)
- The Librarian (Monkaaaaarrrghhh)
- The Death of Rats and the Raven, Quoth (rat skeleton and raven not doing the N-word)
- Gaspode the Wonder Dog (behind Cheery)
- The Amazing Maurice and his Educated Rodents (left to right)

  - Sardines (hat and dentures)
  - Maurice (cat)
  - Darktan (black, carrying rope)
  - Peaches (orange)
  - Dangerous Beans (albino)
  - Hamnpork (grey)

Comment: My first thought on the one you've labelled as Vetinari was Professor Hix of Post-Mortem Communications, based on proximity to the other wizards and general evil wizard vibes.  I don't see another likely candidate for Vetinari, though, and that would have been a significant omission.

Comment: @Simon His proximity to Da Quirm makes me sure that he's Vetinari. He also looks just like Kidby's other drawings of Vetinari.

Comment: I think "AE Pessimal" might be Mr. Teatime - looks like he has one black eye and one white eye. He's also directly in front of Lord Downey, child-like, and seems to have curly brown hair under the red cap.

Comment: @Omegacron I don't know - he doesn't look much like Kidby's other illustrations of Teatime.

Comment: @Werrf - true. Teatime looks more like a dapper gentleman in the other pictures I've seen. I don't recall him wearing glasses or bright red, either - it was just that Teatime is otherwise missing and that fellow is the only one with eyes that don't match.

Comment: The monstrous grinning creature beside Carrot could be Nutt (*Unseen Academicals*).

Comment: Teatime may have recently assisted with Pessimal's inhumation, to acquire his clothes for a disguise.

Comment: I'd reckon that's Moist beside Adorabella, because of the conspicuously golden hat.

Comment: @BinaryWorrier Y'know, I hadn't seen the hat as gold, but you're right - it's the same colour as the watchmen's armour. I'll edit that in.

Comment: Also, I think the luggage deserves a mention, he is a character after all :)

Comment: Valorum has your missing/unsure ones.

Comment: the other answer shows, from Paul Kidby's key, that "Probably Foul Ole Ron" is Dibbler.

Comment: One of the unknown dwarves is surely Grabpot Thundergust. (and looking at the other answer, it's the one on the left)

Answer (score 4):

Artist Paul Kidby offered the following (incomplete) key to the *'Discworld Massif'* on [his instagram site](https://www.instagram.com/p/8H9XCCsiNO/?taken-by=paulkidby). By my count, this is only 39 of the 77 characters depicted.

> Featuring left to right, back row to front row, 'Nijel the
>   Destroyer','Moist von Lipwig','Adora Belle
>   Dearheart','Detritus','Samuel Vimes','C.M.O.T. Dibbler','Otto
>   Chriek','Cohen the Barbarian','Frederick Colon','Magrat
>   Garlick','Verence','Gimlet','Nobby Nobbs','Grabpot
>   Thundergust','Tiffany Aching','Mr Fusspot','Errol' and 'Of the
>   Twilight the Darkness'.

[image]

> Featuring left to right , back row to front row, 'Giamo
>   Casanunder','The Dean','Havelock Vetinari','Leonard of Quirm','Mort
>   Sto Helit','Death','Esmerelda Weatherwax','Ponder Stibbons','Mustrum
>   Ridcully','Rincewind','Gytha Ogg','Greebo','Twoflower','The Luggage'
>   and 'The Librarian'

[image]

> Featuring left to right, back row to front row, 'Ysabell Sto
>   Helit','Lord Downey','Constable Flint','Dr Whiteface','Susan Sto
>   Helit','Alberto Malich','Carrot Ironfoundersson','Angua von
>   Uberwald','Lupine','Lu-Tze','Reg Shoe','Eric Thursley','Cheery
>   Littlebottom','Igor','Snori Snorisson'and 'Gaspode'.

[image]

Comment: The one you have listed as lupine might also be Ludmilla, Mrs. Cake's daughter

Answer (score 0):

I think the man just to the right of Sam Vimes with the top hat is CMOT Dibbler and maybe not Foul old Ron?

Comment: Any reason why you think it's those two?